# facebook group post scraping using selenium gives same author name for all post

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to scrape facebook group data in python. I am using the following code to get data:

```
posts = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name("userContentWrapper")

for count, post in enumerate(posts): 
    analysis = [posts[count].find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-hovercard-referer]").text]
    text = post.find_element_by_class_name("userContent").text
    status = self.strip(text)
    analysis.append(status)
```

The above code gives me 1 author name for all post of facebook group. How can I change the program so that the correct author name will be displayed?

Comment: What's the HTML on your page / link to the page you are automating? It's hard to help at all without that.

Comment: Show us some sample html. Don't expect us to go to facebook(ugh) and find it ourselves

Comment: @KentKostelac Jumping on what you said -- it's quite likely that Facebook has measures in place to prevent UI automation from accurately scraping their pages. I have seen several examples of Facebook making it as hard as possible to scrape page content by forcing inconsistency in page HTML and lazy loading Javascript functions. This may not be the best website for automation.